# gradDescent package and lm function differs

Tags: r, algorithm, package, lm, gradient-descent

I have a problem of understanding about [gradDescent package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gradDescent/index.html) in R. Let's say that I have a data set with one independent variable and i would like to run a simple linear regression on this data and estimate a model and its parameters using batch gradient descent (GD) algorithm.

For example, I am using the dataset given in [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahawker/machine-learning-coursera/master/ex1/ex1data1.txt). First column is independent variable (X) and second column is dependent variable (Y).

I wrote my own R code for batch gradient descent algorithm. I am using learning rate as 0.01 and the number of iteration is 1500. The estimated model is y = -3.630291 + 1.166362 x. The initial values for parameters were both chosen to be 1.

I also wanted to check that my code works correctly or not. I used R built-in function lm package to compare. The parameters are really close to the results given by the linear regression function in R. So in this case the linear regression model obtained by our gradient descent algorithm is y=-3.896 + 1.193 x.

However, recently, I found an R package, gradDescent and I wanted to see how it works. Using the same learning rate and maximum number of iterations, I got the results of the model y=-1.229567+0.9257195x (which those values change everytime that I run because I set the seed=NULL).

```
GD <- function(dataTrain, alpha=0.1, maxIter=10, seed=NULL){
    #convert data.frame dataSet in matrix
    dataTrain <- matrix(unlist(dataTrain), ncol=ncol(dataTrain), byrow=FALSE)
    #shuffle data train
    set.seed(seed)
    dataTrain <- dataTrain[sample(nrow(dataTrain)), ]
    set.seed(NULL)
    #initialize theta
    theta <- getTheta(ncol(dataTrain), seed=seed)
    #bind 1 column to dataTrain
    dataTrain <- cbind(1, dataTrain)
    #parse dataTrain into input and output
    inputData <- dataTrain[,1:ncol(dataTrain)-1]
    outputData <- dataTrain[,ncol(dataTrain)]
    #temporary variables
    temporaryTheta <- matrix(ncol=length(theta), nrow=1)
    updateRule <- matrix(0, ncol=length(theta), nrow=1)
    #constant variables
    rowLength <- nrow(dataTrain)
    #loop the gradient descent
    for(iteration in 1:maxIter){
        error <- (inputData %*% t(theta)) - outputData
        for(column in 1:length(theta)){
            term <- error * inputData[,column]
            #calculate gradient
            gradient <- sum(term) / rowLength
            updateRule[1,column] <- updateRule[1,column] + (alpha*gradient)
            temporaryTheta[1,column] = theta[1,column] - updateRule[1,column] 
        }
        #update all theta in the current iteration
        theta <- temporaryTheta
    }
    result <- theta
    return(result)
}
```

Here, getTheta function is given as,

```
getTheta <- function(columnLength, minTheta=0, maxTheta=1, seed=NULL){
    #create static random
    set.seed(seed)
    #random a value
    thetaList <- runif(columnLength, min=minTheta, max=maxTheta)
    #clear static random
    set.seed(seed)
    #transform into matrix
result <- matrix(unlist(thetaList), ncol=columnLength, nrow=1, byrow=FALSE)
    return(result)
}
```

The package chooses the initial values randomly. Besides, it shuffles the data before running the GD algorithm. I played with it for a bit. I assigned the initial values of parameters as 1s and stopped shuffling the data. However I could not seriously comprehend where everything goes wrong (or correct), the reason I cannot have the same results with my own GD code and lm function of R. Could please someone care to explain?

```
install.packages("gradDescent")
library(gradDescent)

URL_subs <-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahawker/machine-learning-coursera/master/ex1/ex1data1.txt"
data <- read.table(URL_subs, header=FALSE, sep=",")

########## gradDescent Function ########## 
GD(data, alpha = 0.01, maxIter = 1500, seed = NULL)
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] -1.312882 0.9281769

########## R bulit-in function ########## 
model <- lm(data$V2~ ., data = data)
model
#Call:
#  lm(formula = data$V2 ~ ., data = data)
#
#Coefficients:
#  (Intercept)           V1  
#       -3.896        1.193
```

**NOTE**: I can provide what I wrote but basically, I am trying to understand why this package gives more different parameter estimation than lm package.

**EDIT**:
is it because of that line in the code?

```
updateRule[1,column] <- updateRule[1,column] + (alpha*gradient)
```

When the second loop (*for(column in 1:length(theta))*) is over, the code does not reset the updateRule matrix but keeps adding (alpha*gradient) to both columns of the matrix in every iterations. Am I wrong?

When I reset this updateRule matrix to zero after finding the updates of parameters in an iteration, I am getting the model y = -3.570819 +1.160388 x which is very close to what I have and what lm package gives.

---

**EDIT 2**
What was wrong with that gradDescent package was mentioned in my original post. updateRule matrix was not getting reseted. I just add one line of code in the loop and did not change anything else. getTheta and GD functions are as the same as the author of the package posted.

I give two examples to correct it. First data set I use is with one independent variable and the second data set is with two independent variables. For both examples, I use randomly generated initials, which was the idea in the package. For the second example, I normalize the data  because input variables differ by orders of magnitudes. Houses’ area (sizes) are approximately 1000 times larger than bedroom counts.

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
URL_subs <-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahawker/machine-learning-coursera/master/ex1/ex1data1.txt"
data <- read.table(URL_subs, header=FALSE, sep=",")

getTheta <- function(columnLength, minTheta=0, maxTheta=1, seed=NULL){
  #create static random
  set.seed(seed)
  #random a value
  thetaList <- runif(columnLength, min=minTheta, max=maxTheta)
  #clear static random
  set.seed(seed)
  #transform into matrix
  result <- matrix(unlist(thetaList), ncol=columnLength, nrow=1, byrow=FALSE)
  return(result)
}

GD <- function(dataTrain, alpha=0.1, maxIter=10, seed=NULL){
  #convert data.frame dataSet in matrix
  dataTrain <- matrix(unlist(dataTrain), ncol=ncol(dataTrain), byrow=FALSE)
  #shuffle data train
  set.seed(seed)
  dataTrain <- dataTrain[sample(nrow(dataTrain)), ]
  set.seed(NULL)
  #initialize theta
  theta <- getTheta(ncol(dataTrain), seed=seed)
  #bind 1 column to dataTrain
  dataTrain <- cbind(1, dataTrain)
  #parse dataTrain into input and output
  inputData <- dataTrain[,1:ncol(dataTrain)-1]
  outputData <- dataTrain[,ncol(dataTrain)]
  #temporary variables
  temporaryTheta <- matrix(ncol=length(theta), nrow=1)
  updateRule <- matrix(0, ncol=length(theta), nrow=1)
  #constant variables
  rowLength <- nrow(dataTrain)
  #loop the gradient descent
  for(iteration in 1:maxIter){
    error <- (inputData %*% t(theta)) - outputData
    for(column in 1:length(theta)){
      term <- error * inputData[,column]
      #calculate gradient
      gradient <- sum(term) / rowLength
      updateRule[1,column] <- updateRule[1,column] + (alpha*gradient)
      temporaryTheta[1,column] = theta[1,column] - updateRule[1,column] 
    }
    updateRule <- matrix(0, ncol=length(theta), nrow=1)
    #update all theta in the current iteration
    theta <- temporaryTheta
  }
  result <- theta
  return(result)
}

GD(data, alpha = 0.01, maxIter = 1500, seed = NULL)
#          [,1]    [,2]
#[1,] -3.602297 1.16355

########## R built-in lm function ########## 
model <- lm(data$V2~ ., data = data)
model
#Call:
#  lm(formula = data$V2 ~ ., data = data)
#
#Coefficients:
#  (Intercept)           V1  
#       -3.896        1.193
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethen8181/machine-learning/master/linear_regression/housing.txt",
                 header = TRUE, 
                 sep = "," )

getTheta <- function(columnLength, minTheta=0, maxTheta=1, seed=NULL){
  #create static random
  set.seed(seed)
  #random a value
  thetaList <- runif(columnLength, min=minTheta, max=maxTheta)
  #clear static random
  set.seed(seed)
  #transform into matrix
  result <- matrix(unlist(thetaList), ncol=columnLength, nrow=1, byrow=FALSE)
  return(result)
}

GD <- function(dataTrain, alpha=0.1, maxIter=10, seed=NULL){
  #convert data.frame dataSet in matrix
  dataTrain <- matrix(unlist(dataTrain), ncol=ncol(dataTrain), byrow=FALSE)
  #shuffle data train
  set.seed(seed)
  dataTrain <- dataTrain[sample(nrow(dataTrain)), ]
  set.seed(NULL)
  #initialize theta
  theta <- getTheta(ncol(dataTrain), seed=seed)
  #bind 1 column to dataTrain
  dataTrain <- cbind(1, dataTrain)
  #parse dataTrain into input and output
  inputData <- dataTrain[,1:ncol(dataTrain)-1]
  outputData <- dataTrain[,ncol(dataTrain)]
  #temporary variables
  temporaryTheta <- matrix(ncol=length(theta), nrow=1)
  updateRule <- matrix(0, ncol=length(theta), nrow=1)
  #constant variables
  rowLength <- nrow(dataTrain)
  #loop the gradient descent
  for(iteration in 1:maxIter){
    error <- (inputData %*% t(theta)) - outputData
    for(column in 1:length(theta)){
      term <- error * inputData[,column]
      #calculate gradient
      gradient <- sum(term) / rowLength
      updateRule[1,column] <- updateRule[1,column] + (alpha*gradient)
      temporaryTheta[1,column] = theta[1,column] - updateRule[1,column] 
    }
    updateRule <- matrix(0, ncol=length(theta), nrow=1)
    #update all theta in the current iteration
    theta <- temporaryTheta
  }
  result <- theta
  return(result)
}

GD(data, alpha = 0.05, maxIter = 500, seed = NULL)
#         [,1]   [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 340412.7 110630 -6648.375

########## R built-in lm function ########## 
housing <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethen8181/machine-learning/master/linear_regression/housing.txt",
                 header = TRUE, 
                 sep = "," )

normalized <- apply(housing[ , -3 ], 2, scale)
normalized_data <- data.frame(cbind(normalized, price = housing$price))
model <- lm( price ~ ., data = normalized_data)
model

#Call:
#  lm(formula = price ~ ., data = normalized_data)
#
#Coefficients:
#  (Intercept)         area     bedrooms  
#       340413       110631        -6649
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right.
I think the line of `updateRule` works like a momentum.  I.e., the direction of change in the current iteration retains (partially) in the next iteration.
But you should just not add the new gradient, but your `updateRule` to decay, so that any wrong direction in the past is washed away as the iteration goes on.

Below, I changed only one line of your function.  When updating the `updateRule`, I multiplied it by 0.2.  Any value between zero and one would work too (but must be strictly smaller than one).

Also, I increased the number of iteration.  In my system, I got:

```
##              [,1]     [,2]
##    [1,] -3.895781 1.193034
```

which is very similar result to `lm` result.

```
GD <- function(dataTrain, alpha=0.1, maxIter=10, seed=NULL){
  #convert data.frame dataSet in matrix
  dataTrain <- matrix(unlist(dataTrain), ncol=ncol(dataTrain), byrow=FALSE)
  #shuffle data train
  set.seed(seed)
  dataTrain <- dataTrain[sample(nrow(dataTrain)), ]
  set.seed(NULL)
  #initialize theta
  theta <- getTheta(ncol(dataTrain), seed=seed)
  #bind 1 column to dataTrain
  dataTrain <- cbind(1, dataTrain)
  #parse dataTrain into input and output
  inputData <- dataTrain[,1:ncol(dataTrain)-1]
  outputData <- dataTrain[,ncol(dataTrain)]
  #temporary variables
  temporaryTheta <- matrix(ncol=length(theta), nrow=1)
  updateRule <- matrix(0, ncol=length(theta), nrow=1)
  #constant variables
  rowLength <- nrow(dataTrain)
  #loop the gradient descent
  for(iteration in 1:maxIter){
    error <- (inputData %*% t(theta)) - outputData
    for(column in 1:length(theta)){
      term <- error * inputData[,column] 
      #calculate gradient
      gradient <- sum(term) / rowLength
      #updateRule[1,column] <- updateRule[1,column] + (alpha*gradient)
      updateRule[1,column] <- 0.2*updateRule[1,column] + (alpha*gradient)
      temporaryTheta[1,column] = theta[1,column] - updateRule[1,column] 
    }
    #update all theta in the current iteration
    theta <- temporaryTheta
  }
  result <- theta
  return(result)
}

getTheta <- function(columnLength, minTheta=0, maxTheta=1, seed=NULL){
  #create static random
  set.seed(seed)
  #random a value
  thetaList <- runif(columnLength, min=minTheta, max=maxTheta)
  #clear static random
  set.seed(seed)
  #transform into matrix
  result <- matrix(unlist(thetaList), ncol=columnLength, nrow=1, byrow=FALSE)
  return(result)
}

#install.packages("gradDescent")
library(gradDescent)

URL_subs <-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahawker/machine-learning-coursera/master/ex1/ex1data1.txt"
data <- read.table(URL_subs, header=FALSE, sep=",")

########## gradDescent Function ########## 
GD(data, alpha = 0.01, maxIter = 15000, seed = 1)


########## R bulit-in function ########## 
model <- lm(data$V2~ ., data = data)
model
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! This is not my package or function. I also made a small change like resetting update rule and now i am getting the similar results with lm package. I will edit my post and show the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest version of 'gradDescent' package(3.0version, released at 2018-01-25). And the issue you pointed out seems having been fixed.

Using the data in your example, I can get the similar results with lm models.